# Which one of these is the right syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

Beginner programmer here. I'm making a simple program to display my computers local IP-address, and the external IP-address of my network. This really isn't a problem, but more of just a question.

So, which one of these formats is the preferred syntax?

1.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

def FetchLocalAddress():
    hostname = gethostname()
    ip = gethostbyname(hostname)
    return ip

def FetchExternalAddress():
    ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
    return ip

try:
    print('Local ip-address: {}'.format(str(FetchLocalAddress())))
    print('External ip-address: {}'.format(str(FetchExternalAddress())))
except ConnectionError:
    print('No internet connection.')
```

2.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

def FetchLocalAddress():
    hostname = gethostname()
    ip = gethostbyname(hostname)
    return ip

def FetchExternalAddress():
    try:
        ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
        return ip
    except ConnectionError:
        print('No internet connection.')

print('Local ip-address: {}'.format(str(FetchLocalAddress())))
external = FetchExternalAddress()
if external is not None:
    print('External ip-address: {}'.format(str(external)))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the first one. It has the advantage to always return a `string`, and if it doesn't, it throws an exception. This is a predictable and understandable behavior. It means that it's easier to document and that someone with no access to your source code can understand and use the `FetchExternalAddress()` method.

As long as you properly document your method indicating that it returns a `string` and throws `Exception` if no valid Internet connection is detected.

You also should avoid side-effects like your `print("No internet connection")` in your method as it might result in unexpected prints to the user.